# crashing issue with large dataset on R Studio

Tags: r, rstudio

I am dealing with a large dataset, large in a sense that my dataframe contains 8-9 million observations and 20 columns. My R Studio crashes frequently , I am wondering what others are doing to mitigate this problem ?

Comment: Do you have the same problem in R console?

Comment: I believe this is not the correct place to ask this question... Please ask here https://support.rstudio.com/ .. And same question https://support.rstudio.com/hc/communities/public/questions/200656727-R-session-crashes-with-large-data-sets-using-dcast-reshape2-

Comment: @Pascal, it has been almost 2 years since I have used R  console :), thanks Backtrack I will check that thread

Comment: I mean, out of RStudio.

Comment: If Rstudio crashes, use another IDE or raw R. Also please add more information about your system and functions used to import the data set.

Comment: You don't even tell when it crashes (during import, during certain operations, ...).

Comment: @Roland, and Roman, usually when I load the data and do some manipulations things work fine, but when I try to clear the console using Cntrl+L , thats when it goes into deep freez, I noticed this only happens when I am dealing with datasets that have around 4 million observations or more